# Print Double with two digits both before and after the decimal separator

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, string-formatting

I'm trying to print a Double with this format : 01.87 or 23.98.

I've found how to print only 2 digits after the point but I don't found how to print 2 digits before.

This is my code for the moment:

```
let str = NSString(format: "%.2f", myValueToPrint as! Double)
```

How can I print my double like 00.00?

Comment: You can use `String` instead of `NSString`.

Comment: @ColGraff Right ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use like this:

```
let str = NSString(format: "%05.2f",  myValueToPrint as! Double)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also user [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

```
let a_double: Double = 2.348

let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
formatter.format = "#,##00.00"


if let the_value = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: a_double))
{
    print(the_value) // 02.35
}
```

Comment: I want 01.45 this method prints 1.45 no?

Comment: Then use "0" instead of "#" in format pattern: formatter.positiveFormat = "00.00"